# LINQ to SQL exception when converting nullable value to non-nullable using Convert

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, null, invalidoperationexception

## Problem

Given the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

and a queryable, where `MyTable.NullableDateTime` is a `DateTime?` mapped to an SQL `datetime`:

```
IQueryable<MyTable> table = //something
```

Running the following produces an exception when the row's `NullableDateTime` column is `NULL`:

```
table.Select(row => new MyClass
{
    DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(row.NullableDateTime)
}).ToArray();
```

The error is:

> InvalidOperationException
>
> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.DateTime which is a non-nullable value type.

## What I've Tried

1. Looking at the generated SQL:

   ```
   CONVERT(DateTime,[t0].[NullableDateTime]) AS [NullableDateTime]
   ```
2. Running the query before performing the `Select`. This works around the problem, but I don't want to run this on the client side just to work around the problem.
3. Using `row.GetDefaultValue()` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime`. This yields a different error:

   > SqlException
   >
   > The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

   The `GetDefaultValue` method call is converted to the following SQL:

   ```
   COALESCE([t0].[NullableDateTime],'1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM') AS [NullableDateTime]
   ```

Comment: What type is `NullableDateTime`? I assume you can't change the type in the database...

Comment: It's an SQL `datetime` mapped to a .NET `DateTime?`.

Comment: But why is `MyClass.DateTime` not nullable? You wouldn't need any conversion if it was.

Comment: @GertArnold, because I'm working on a badly-written project by someone else and I'm required to make minimal changes.

Comment: Ah, yes, sounds familiar :). I think STO's answer will do, except that you can convert nulls to `default(DateTime)` because you're within .Net. Bad thing is, you'll have to check for `DateTime.MinValue` where `MyClass.DateTime` is addressed.

Comment: @GertArnold, `default(DateTime)` doesn't work because, as the accepted answer implied, it's outside of the range of SQL's `datetime`, so when the query is run, it produces an invalid SQL `datetime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to use `??` operator with some default value of DateTime (but not `default(DateTime)` because it's value 1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM is out of range of valid values for SQL datetime type. You probably can use [SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.aspx) in right side of `??`.